# How to create and ID by type and also an parent-child ID using lookup table?

Tags: sql-server, import, structure, parent-child, lookup

I would like to import a txt file that contains an defined structure. I need to create an identity for every record type and also a parent-child id that will make easy to join specific record types.

I also have a lookup table that says which is the parent record type:

LOOKUP TABLE

```
TYPE     |  STRUCTURE LEVEL  |  PARENT
A        |  1                |
B        |  2                |  A
C        |  3                |  B
D        |  3                |  B
E        |  2                |  A
F        |  3                |  E
```

And my data looks similar to:

```
TYPE     |    INFO
A        |    dummy
B        |    dummy2
C        |    dummy3
C        |    dummy4
D        |    dummy5
B        |    dummy6
B        |    dummy7
C        |    dummy8
B        |    dummy9
D        |    dummy10
E        |    dummy11
F        |    dummy12
```

If you look at table data, there are some situations that I need to cover:

- First "B" record has 3 children (two "C" type and one "D")
- Second "B" record has no child
- Third "B" record has no "D" child
- Fourth "B" record has no "C" child
- "B" and "E" records are siblings and the same for "C" and "D"

I would like to get the following result (does not matther whether result is in a single table or not):

Table A

```
ID     |     PARENT_ID     |    TYPE      | INFO
1      |                   |    A         | dummy
```

Table B

```
ID     |     PARENT_ID     |    TYPE      | INFO
1      |    1              |    B         | dummy2
2      |    1              |    B         | dummy6
3      |    1              |    B         | dummy7
```

Table C

```
ID     |     PARENT_ID     |    TYPE      | INFO
1      |    1              |    C         | dummy3
2      |    1              |    C         | dummy4
3      |    3              |    C         | dummy8
```

Table D

```
ID     |     PARENT_ID     |    TYPE      | INFO
1      |    1              |    D         | dummy5
2      |    4              |    D         | dummy10
```

Table E

```
ID     |     PARENT_ID     |    TYPE      | INFO
1      |    1              |    E         | dummy11
```

Table F

```
ID     |     PARENT_ID     |    TYPE      | INFO
1      |    1              |     F        | dummy12
```

Sorry for the long explanation and thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. My workaround was develop my own C# program for importing data into SQL server.